# Корректно ли составлено предложение с местоимением "их"?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Возник спор насчет корректности приведенного предложения. Кажется, что "их" - это мужчины, а не животные. Существует ли правило для такой ситуации?

> В природе происходит всякое, но животных, даже самых кровожадных или противных, не могу прировнять к мужчинам, потому что вся их жизнь - это инстинкты.

Comment: меня больше смущает противопоставление мужчин и животных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Заданное** предложение: *В природе происходит всякое, но **животных**, даже самых кровожадных или противных, не могу прировнять к **мужчинам,** потому что вся **их** жизнь — это инстинкты.*

**Редактирование**: *В природе происходит всякое, но животных, даже самых кровожадных или противных, не могу приравнять к мужчинам. Ведь вся  жизнь **животных**  — это инстинкты.*

Правило есть, это **[Розенталь §169. Личные местоимения. §170. Возвратные и притяжательные местоимения](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/60.htm) .**

Местоимение ***их*** — притяжательное.  В правилах (для различных местоимений) используется такой **принцип**: **местоимение** 3-го лица обычно заменяет ближайшее к нему **предшествующее** существительное в такой же форме.

Возможность **соотнесения** местоимения с разными словами в **предшествующем** тексте может служить источником **неясности** или двусмысленности. В этих случаях необходима **правка.**